# Show that for $\alpha, \beta > 0$ and $0 < \delta < 1$, that $\left| \alpha\beta -1 \right| \leq 3\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

I am working on a pretty long proof, which is irrelevant here. But in one step, I need to prove the following:

> Let $\alpha > 0$, $\beta > 0$ and $0 < \delta < 1$ be real values with
>    $\left|\alpha - 1\right| \leq \delta$ and $\left|\beta - 1\right| \leq
>  \delta$. Show that: $$\left|\alpha\beta -1 \right| \leq 3\delta$$

I'm sadly stuck and don't even know where to start here, which is holding me back in my proof. How can this be proven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|ab-1| \leq |ab-a+a-1|\leq |a||b-1|+|a-1|$$ $$\leq (|a-1|+1)|b-1|+|a-1|$$ $$\leq \delta^2+\delta+\delta <3\delta$$

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. I will accept your answer as soon as it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

From $|\alpha - 1| \leq \delta$ and $|\beta - 1| \leq \delta$, we have 
$$  1-\delta \leq \alpha \leq 1 + \delta  $$
and
$$  1-\delta \leq \beta \leq 1 + \delta  \text{,}  $$
so
$$  1-2\delta + \delta^2 \leq \alpha \beta \leq 1+2\delta + \delta^2  \text{.}  $$
Then 
$$  -2\delta + \delta^2 \leq \alpha \beta - 1\leq 2\delta + \delta^2  \text{.}  $$
Since $0 < \delta < 1$, the triangle inequality gives $|-2 \delta + \delta^2| < 2 \delta + \delta^2 < 3 \delta$.  So you have the slightly stronger
$$  |\alpha \beta - 1| < 2\delta +\delta^2 < 3\delta \text{.}  $$

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the last estimate $2\delta +\delta^2 < 3\delta^2$ is wrong for $0 < \delta < 1$.

Comment: @MartinR : Oops.  One too many squares.  Thanks! and Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm using Latin letters rather than Greek because I'm lazy.)

$(a-1)(b-1)
=ab-a-b+1
=ab-1-(a-1)-(b-1)
$

so

$ab-1
=(a-1)+(b-1)+(a-1)(b-1)
$.

Taking absolute values,

$|ab-1|
\le 2d+d^2
\lt 3d
$.